# system statusbar problem in activities android studio

Tags: android

I have an app from 2 years ago that I recently updated and now the navigationbar
of the system is disproportionately large. The problem seems to be only for Android 12 and up. Attach some captures in light and dark mode

Thank you so much in advance for your help, I have a lot to catch up on.

PD: I've tried creating a new blank activity and the problem continues, I repeat it's an app-wide problem

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?colorPrimaryVariant">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/splash_tvCreatorName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/google_sans_regular"
            android:text="Hi, everyone!"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="?colorOnPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/app_creator_name_size"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Capture run app (dark mode) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqQXG.jpg)

Capture run app (white mode) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oieAy.png)

Capture theme.xml (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUEBr.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem was that I needed to add the targetSdk in build.gradle, I didn't have a complication error and maybe I deleted it manually, I don't think the ARR migration deleted it directly. Needless to say, I had to disassemble the whole app to find that little detail, I hope maybe it will help you next.

```
android {
    compileSdk 34

    //the compression of webp file during build causes problem with FileDescriptor in ContentProvider.
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplication"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 18
.....
```

[Screenshot of build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBnKK.png)